# Spring securiyy: Access is denied

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have `security-context.xml`:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user*" access="hasRole('REGISTERED_USER')"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <security:user password="password" name="user" authorities="REGISTERED_USER" />
                <security:user password="password" name="manager" authorities="BOOKING_MANAGER" />

            </security:user-service>

        </security:authentication-provider>

    </security:authentication-manager>
```

As expected I was redirected to `login` when I am trying access `/user`. 
But I expect access be granted after I login as `user/password`. It doesn't happen and I get:

```
HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied.
```

What do I understand wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st option:** You have to add prefix `ROLE_`:

```
<security:user password="password" name="user" authorities="ROLE_REGISTERED_USER" />
```

http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-secure-view-layer-using-taglibs/

**2nd option:** you can redefine `RoleVoiter` bean and make it work w/o prefix:

```
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```